# iPod Classic 160GB deletes all files and isn't recognized on PC

Tags: itunes, performance, software, ipod-classic

I purchased a 160 GB iPod Classic last year. Regularly throughout the year I found that the iPod would often freeze and need to be reset every time it was plugged into my computer. Formerly an Asus running Windows 7 but more recently a Lenovo G780 running Windows 8.

Last night after syncing music to my iPod (roughly 86 GB of the 160 are used), I ejected it from my computer. The iPod started to reset itself, which I figured wasn't too different as it still needed to be reset before syncing every time. This time however it brought me to the Language selection screen, once picking English the date said December 2000 and all of my files were gone. Luckily everything is backed up on my computer, however once plugging in (didn't need to reset this time) it connected without showing up in Windows or iTunes. Everytime I disconnect it resets itself and takes me back to the Language selection screen again.

When I try to open any files related to the iPod (My Computers, iTunes, etc.) the program on my computer freezes as well I'm noticing today.

Any idea how I can get the iPod even to restore it to factory settings?

***EDIT***
I was able to get into diagnostics mode, but don't know what these numbers mean:

Retracts: 9
Reallocs: 32
Pending Sectors: 136
PowerOn Hours: 249
Start/Stops: 22492
Temp: Current 32c
Temp: Min 57c
Temp: Max 241c

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the only way to restore it, but that would involve connecting it to your computer. You might also be able to use another computer to do this: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1339

You could also see what the Genius Bar at the Apple Store says.